# lodash pick in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects like this:

```
{
  "sizes":{
     "thumbnail":{
        "height":300,
        "width":300,
        "url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-300x300.jpg",
        "orientation":"landscape"
     },
     "medium":{
        "height":267,
        "width":400,
        "url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-400x267.jpg",
        "orientation":"landscape"
     },
     "large":{
        "height":441,
        "width":660,
        "url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-1024x684.jpg",
        "orientation":"landscape"
     },
     "full":{
        "url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web.jpg",
        "height":1200,
        "width":1796,
        "orientation":"landscape"
     }
  },
  "mime":"image/jpeg",
  "type":"image",
  "subtype":"jpeg",
  "id":3589,
  "url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web.jpg",
  "alt":"",
  "link":"http://example.com/web/",
  "caption":""
}
```

I'm using the following snippet to create a new array with just the `alt`, `caption`, `id` and `url` keys in the array:

```
images.map( ( image ) => pick( image, [ 'alt', 'caption', 'id', 'url' ] ) ),
```

My question is, how can I pick the `sizes.thumbnail.url` key instead of the root `url` key? Is it possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an object with the url property and the value of `sizes.thumbnail.url` using [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get), and combine it with to the results of the `_.pick()`.

**Note:** I've used [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to merge the results, but you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or lodash's equivalent instead.

```js
const images = [{"sizes":{"thumbnail":{"height":300,"width":300,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-300x300.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"medium":{"height":267,"width":400,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-400x267.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"large":{"height":441,"width":660,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-1024x684.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"full":{"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web.jpg","height":1200,"width":1796,"orientation":"landscape"}},"mime":"image/jpeg","type":"image","subtype":"jpeg","id":3589,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web.jpg","alt":"","link":"http://example.com/web/","caption":""}];

const result = images.map((image) => ({
  ..._.pick(image, ['alt', 'caption', 'id']),
  url: _.get(image, 'sizes.thumbnail.url')
}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

A more generic solution would a function that accepts a list of paths, and generate an array of pairs [last part of path, value]. The function converts the pairs to an object using [`_.fromPairs()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#fromPairs) (or [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)):

```js
const deepPick = (paths, obj) => 
  _.fromPairs(paths.map(p => [
    _.last(p.split('.')),
    _.get(obj, p),
  ]))

const images = [{"sizes":{"thumbnail":{"height":300,"width":300,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-300x300.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"medium":{"height":267,"width":400,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-400x267.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"large":{"height":441,"width":660,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-1024x684.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"full":{"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web.jpg","height":1200,"width":1796,"orientation":"landscape"}},"mime":"image/jpeg","type":"image","subtype":"jpeg","id":3589,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web.jpg","alt":"","link":"http://example.com/web/","caption":""}];

const result = images.map(image => deepPick(
  ['alt', 'caption', 'id', 'sizes.thumbnail.url'], 
  image
));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You deserve a medal for this!

Comment: deep pick... sorry makes me laugh haha

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [{"sizes":{"thumbnail":{"height":300,"width":300,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-300x300.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"medium":{"height":267,"width":400,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-400x267.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"large":{"height":441,"width":660,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web-1024x684.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"full":{"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web.jpg","height":1200,"width":1796,"orientation":"landscape"}},"mime":"image/jpeg","type":"image","subtype":"jpeg","id":3589,"url":"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/web.jpg","alt":"","link":"http://example.com/web/","caption":""}];


var result = _.map(array, v => ({"alt":v.alt, "caption":v.caption, "id":v.id, "url":v.sizes.thumbnail.url}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use plain js,

```js
function pickfromobject(object, key){
 var parts= key.split('.')
 if(parts.length > 1){
  var tempkey = parts.shift()
  if(!object[tempkey]){
   return null
  } else{
   return pickfromobject(object[tempkey], parts.join('.'))
  }
 } else{
  return object[parts[0]]
 }
}


function pick(arr, key){
 var result = []
 for(var i =0;i<arr.length; i++){
  result.push({[key]: pickfromobject(arr[i], key)})
 }
 return result
}

var a = [{a: {c:{d:1}}, b:2}, {a:{c:{d:3}}, b:3}]

console.log(pick(a, 'a.c.d'))
```

Comment: This I think is a very verbose example that includes way more surface area for bugs. Use a Lodash or underscore option would be preferred in most any case

Comment: "plain js" is usually called "VanillaJs".