# How to get values from object property array with lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following obj:

```
 { Id: '11ea9563-1a4c-c21b-904f-00ff98e8d5ab',
  Email: 'Email',
  Password:
   { type: 'Buffer',
     data:
      [ Buffer value] },
  roles: [ { Name: 'Developer', userroles: [Object] } ],
  Events:
   [ { Id: '11ea9556-c025-39ae-904f-00ff98e8d5ab'} ] }
```

I want to get the `Id`, `roles.Name` and `Events.Id` with lodash:

```
_.pick(obj, ['Id', 'roles.Name', 'Events.Id']),
```

But with the above I only manage to get the Id.

How can I accomplish this with lodash?

Comment: Maybe the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096091/lodash-pick-in-nested-array can help you out.

Comment: @marco-a Thanks for the link but the accepted answer there is working with an array of objects. In my case it is one object but has two array properties. Any ideas?

Comment: If you scroll down a little there's a function `deepPick` in the answer, maybe this function works out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const answer = {
   id: obj.Id,
   roles: _.map(obj.roles, 'Name'),
   events: _.map(obj.Events, 'Id')
};
```

```js
const obj = { 
  Id: '11ea9563-1a4c-c21b-904f-00ff98e8d5ab',
  Email: 'Email',
  Password: {
    type: 'Buffer'
  },
  roles: [ { Name: 'Developer', userroles: [Object] } ],
  Events:
   [ { Id: '11ea9556-c025-39ae-904f-00ff98e8d5ab'} ]
}

answer = {
   id: obj.Id,
   roles: _.map(obj.roles, 'Name'),
   events: _.map(obj.Events, 'Id')
};


console.log(answer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer BUT i only want the Name for roles, in this canse Im getting: 

  roles:
   { '0': { Name: 'Developer', userroles: [Object] }

I dont want the userroles prop to be there

Comment: Thanks m8. I added my own below but liked yours alot more since roles becomes [Developer, Admin, etc] but in my solution: [{Name:"Developer"}, {Name:"Admin"}, {Name:"Etc"}]

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read [here](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/deep-picking/), You can't use `_.pick` for deep picking. Use a combination of `_.get` and `_.map`

```
var _ = require("lodash")

const data = {
  Id: '11ea9563-1a4c-c21b-904f-00ff98e8d5ab',
  Email: 'Email',
  Password: { type: 'Buffer' },
  roles: [
    { Name: 'Developer', userroles: [Object] }
  ],
  Events: [ { Id: '11ea9556-c025-39ae-904f-00ff98e8d5ab' } ]
}

var result = {
  Id: data.Id,
  Email: data.Email,
  'roles.Name': _.map(data.roles, 'Name'), /* Returns expected array of object values */
  'roles.Name': _.map(data.roles, o => _.pick(o, ['Name'])), /* Returns expected array of object */
  'Events.Id': _.map(data.Events, 'Id'),
};


console.log(result)
```

Comment: `_.get` isn't necessary here. Just use `data.roles` instead of `_.get(data, 'roles')`

Comment: This gives perspective on other way to do it. A bit more bloated than @user125661 answer but never the less I learned from this, vote up!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best answer for this but right now Ive done the following:

Thanks to @marco-a

I analyzed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096091/lodash-pick-in-nested-array) and came up with the following:

```
const deepPick = (paths, obj) => _.fromPairs(paths.map(p => [_.last(p.split('.')), _.get(obj, p)]));
```

My own solution so far:

```
  const data = _.pick(obj, ['Id', 'roles', 'events']);

  const userRoles = data.roles.map(role=> deepPick(['Name'], role));

  const eventIds = data.events.map(eventId=> deepPick(['Id'], eventId));
```

The output becomes:

```
{
    "id": "11ea9563-1a4c-c21b-904f-00ff98e8d5ab",
    "roles": [
      {
        "Name": "Developer"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Admin"
      }
    ],
    "events": [
      {
        "Id": "11ea9556-c025-39ae-904f-00ff98e8d5ab"
      }
    ]
  },
}
```